# Why is JObject.Parse creating an object inside an object from a string?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a string value:

`var responseString = {"ErrorType":"ServerError","Message":"Incoming data error.","Properties":null}`

When I call `JObject.Parse(responseString);`, I get the following dynamic object:

```
{{  
"ErrorType": "ServerError",  
"Message": "Incoming data error.",  
"Properties": null
}}
```

Why is JObject creating a dynamic object that is an object wrapped in an object?  I was hoping to write code to access the Message property such as `responseMessage.Message as string`, but that throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following code in LinqPad:

```
var responseString = "{\"ErrorType\":\"ServerError\",\"Message\":\"Incoming data error.\",\"Properties\":null}";
dynamic responseMessage = JObject.Parse(responseString);
var msg = (string) responseMessage.Message;
msg.Dump();
```

In the output, I get the desired `Incoming data error.` string, so it looks like it is doing what it should. How does your code look? And what version of Json.NET are you using? Also, it is NOT possible to use `as` to convert to string, as this will return `null`, since the value is a `JToken`. You need the explicit cast.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation... that helped narrow down my issues exactly.  I was using `as`.  And then when it wasn't working correctly, I tried to use VS's watch window to test different properties and those would give me the error message.